# How to compare @ElementCollection and set in Spring JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I need to find games that have all the locations from the incoming set (but this does not mean that the game only has these locations, there may be more of them), but now this search does not work at all and displays all the games in which there is at least 1 location

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Game g" +
            " WHERE (:gameTitle is null or g.gameTitle = :gameTitle)" +
            " AND (:gameType is null or g.gameType = :gameType)" +
            " AND (:locations is null or g.gameLocations in :locations)")
    List<Game> findGames(
            @Param("gameTitle") String title,
            @Param("gameType") String type,
            @Param("locations") Set<String> locations);
```

This is set from entity

```
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> gamePlatforms;
```

Can someone help me please? ^-^

Comment: all parameters in a IN clause are joined with OR. So your result is correct. But you need AND. So cannot do it in a JPQL query. The best way would be to use the Criteria API